# What is the output sequence of a Decimation filter

Tags: filters, decimation

Consider x(n) as input, y(n) as output & h(n) as filter coefficient. The filter is of 16 taps(N=16) from 0 to 15. The decimation factor of the filter is 4.
When I apply x(n) to this 16 tap decimation filter with decimation factor 4, what is the output that i should get?
What is the general relation(give formula) between x(n) & y(n)?
Also, if you can simplify that formula by giving what y(0), y(1), y(2) will be in terms of x(n) & h(n).
This is the decimation filter using DSP 48 slice of xilinx
[image: This is the decimation filter architecture using DSP48 slice of Xilinx]

Comment: For a Decimation filter the output y(n)=x(Mn) where M is the decimation Factor greater than or equal to 1. for a decimation by 4 filter, y(0)=x(0); y(1)=x(4) and so on. Can you put up the impulse response of the 16 tap decimation filter so that we can see what it is?

Comment: On a side note, to downsample by a rational fraction M/L, first upsample by L and then downsample by M.

Comment: @Sudarsan I want generic formula. example, for normal FIR filter, y(0)=x(0)*h(0), y(1)=x(1)*h(0)+x(0)*h(1) & so on. I want to write a code for it in verilog using DSP48 slice

Comment: @Sudarsan Besides, I am not looking for decimation of x(n). My question is x(n) passed through a decimation "filter". They are not the same

Comment: Well that depends upon the 16-taps that you've got in your hand doesn't  it?. Generally for any LTI filter system the output is just the convolution. I don't know of a generic 16-tap FIR decimating filter(maybe it's that I haven't come across it, sorry not being of much help here !). Can you provide the link to such a filter so that I can have a look at it?

Comment: @Sudarsan added the pic. It is done using DSP48 slice of xilinx